# Mockito cannot mock JdbcTemplate

Tags: junit, mockito, jdbctemplate

I'm currently working on setting up JUnit tests using Mockito.  As of right now, I'm unable to get a very basic test to run:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestDAO {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestDAO.class.getName());

    @Mock
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();

    @InjectMocks
    private TestDAOImpl dao;

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Hello init");
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllEntries() {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

For the moment, all I want is to see if it can print out hello world.  Every time I run the test, though, I receive an error that:

```
Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Which seems to point to the JdbcTemplate as the culprit. I'm trying to mock that database connection so I can mock CRUD operations later.

This is my first time using Mockito, so any help would be appreciated.  The full stack trace is below:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 25.5-b02
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0_05-b13
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 7
OS version         : 6.1


Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

    at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.beforeEach(MockitoExtension.java:165)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor$$Lambda$192/20816428.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:155)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:128)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:113)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor$$Lambda$142/16902902.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor$$Lambda$145/18524506.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor$$Lambda$142/16902902.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor$$Lambda$145/18524506.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor$$Lambda$142/16902902.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:211)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterEachCallbacks$11(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor$$Lambda$196/31005110.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:229)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor$$Lambda$195/6646756.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1234)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:227)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAfterEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:216)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:119)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$ForTypeArgument.resolve(TypeDescription.java:3083)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$Delegator$Chained.resolve(TypeDescription.java:2868)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$ForTypeArgument.resolve(TypeDescription.java:3056)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$AnnotationReader$Delegator.asList(TypeDescription.java:2822)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfTypeVariable$ForLoadedType.getDeclaredAnnotations(TypeDescription.java:5130)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfTypeVariable$Symbolic.getDeclaredAnnotations(TypeDescription.java:4941)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfTypeVariable$WithAnnotationOverlay.getDeclaredAnnotations(TypeDescription.java:5204)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.apply(AnnotationAppender.java:639)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.onTypeVariable(AnnotationAppender.java:611)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.onTypeVariable(AnnotationAppender.java:333)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfTypeVariable.accept(TypeDescription.java:4852)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.onParameterizedType(AnnotationAppender.java:601)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.AnnotationAppender$ForTypeAnnotations.onParameterizedType(AnnotationAppender.java:333)
    at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfParameterizedType.accept(TypeDescription.java:4372)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.MethodAttributeAppender$ForInstrumentedMethod.apply(MethodAttributeAppender.java:183)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.attribute.MethodAttributeAppender$Compound.apply(MethodAttributeAppender.java:425)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyAttributes(TypeWriter.java:617)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:609)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:528)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:4167)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:1653)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:183)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:163)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:2669)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make(DynamicType.java:2771)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:128)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:137)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:344)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:159)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:353)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:69)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1895)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotationForMock(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:41)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:19)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
    at org.mockito.internal.framework.DefaultMockitoSession.<init>(DefaultMockitoSession.java:36)
    at org.mockito.internal.session.DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.startMocking(DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder.java:78)
    ... 56 more
```

Comment: Can you share the code of TestDAOImpl too?

Answer (score 0):

Please recheck your imports and don't mix JUnit 4 and JUnit 5, it may be the source of your problem.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@ExtendWith ( MockitoExtension.class )
public class SampleTest {

    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();

    @InjectMocks
    private TestObject testObject;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        System.out.println( "Hello init" );
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllEntries() {
        System.out.println( "hello world" );
    }
}
```

It is working perfectly with my example. Be careful with `@Test` annotation - it has to be JUnit 5 annotation, moreover `@Rule` annotation doesn't exist in JUnit 5.

If it won't help, please show us your dependencies with versions.